# Why does this printing script ignore my custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a blog template with multiple features, among which is a *print article* feature.

For this purpose, I use **[Print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/)** and some custom CSS. The custom CSS is print-specific:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/print.css" media="print">
```

The content that needs to be printed:

```
<main class="content" id="article-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sapiente? Veritatis error nemo exercitationem molestias praesentium perspiciatis est officia quod sequi mollitia, omnis optio? Labore autem doloribus quidem quos consectetur?</p>
</main>
```

The print button:

```
<a href="#" id="print_btn" onclick="printJS('article-content', 'html')">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
</a>
```

#### The problem

Although the page *does* get printed, my *custom CSS is ignored*.

#### Questions

1. What is the cause of this problem?
2. What is an easy and reliable way to fix it?

Comment: _"my custom CSS is ignored"_ - does it get applied, when you just try and print the page via the browser's default print menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation you provided:

> "This allow us to pass one or more css files URLs that should be
> applied to the html being printed. Value can be a string with a single
> URL or an array with multiple URLs."

The css property invoking the script will make what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Inlcude a stylesheet specifically for printing, then style it according to your desire.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />

<!-- css -->
@media print {
#content, #page {
width: 100%; 
margin: 0; 
float: none;
}
         
@page { margin: 2cm }

body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.3;
background: #fff !important;
color: #000;
}

h1 {
font-size: 24pt;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

h2, h3, h4 {
font-size: 14pt;
margin-top: 25px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}            
}
```